# Changing all instances of a class using different threads

Tags: java, multithreading, instance

I have written a piece of code in which I make multiple instances of a class, each instance has its own thread. However, when one of the instances meets a condition (in this case, when its x co-ordinate is a specific value) I want all instances of the class to change direction.

Anyone have some ideas of how to approach this?
Thanks.

EDIT: This is the code changes the direction of the objects. At the moment the object only changes when each its x co-ordinate reaches 750. I want all objects to change direction as soon as one object has reached 750.

```
public void run() {
    while(thread != null) {
        while(x <= 750) {
            if(x == 750) y+=100;
            x+=1;
            try {
                thread.sleep(10);
            } catch(Exception e) {}
        }
        while(x >= 10) {
            if(x == 10) y+=100;
            x-=1;
            try {
                thread.sleep(10);
            } catch(Exception e) {}
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add your code!

Comment: Update all your objects once per timestep. Don't use any more threads than you need to. Then you can change the direction when updating or use a static field.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need more than one thread to do this as using multiple threads is more likely to make you simulator a) slower b) unreproducable as there is no guarantee when a thread will run or for how long.

You can change the direction by altering the fields which determine the direction.  To be able to access them all I suggest you put them in a collection which you can access.  Needless to say you have to do this is a thread safe way as you have multiple threads.

If you are not sure how to do this, I suggest using just one thread to start with and change to multiple threads when you know how and are sure it will help.

Answer (score 0):

First off, there is only one instance of any class in Java -- classes are static.  I think you are creating instances of objects that are of that class type.  It might sound like arguing semantics, but "class scoped" is not the same as "instance scoped" so it's an important piece of information to have.

You might want to start with the [Java Concurrency lesson from oracle.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) The core problem you are describing (thread communication) is pretty common.  You should be able to get tons of information from the Googles.  But in short -- you need a common piece of information that is shared across all threads.

Comment: This could work, if I keep a note of the distance between the objects and make this constant. Also thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Not so hard.
first keep all threads instances, then whenever a thread meets the condition, then changes the others too. something like this.

```
class Foo implements Runnable{

    private final static List<Foo> instances=new ArrayList<Foo>();

        private volatile Direction d=Direction.U;
        public changeDirection(Direction d){}
          public void run(){
          //
            if(<<GOT THE POINT>>){
               synchronized(instances){
                 for(Foo fx:instances){fx.changeDirection(<<Desired direction>>);}
               }
            }
          //
          }
        }
        enum Direction{U,B,L,R}
```